# Could I request volume to get encrypted volume through Softlayer API

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Currently, I would call 'SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getUpgradeItemPrices' to get local or san disk and call 'SoftLayer_Product_Package/id' (which block is based on '222') to get external disks. And I noticed that SoftLayer portal could provision an encrypted file/block volume.

And my question is that how could I request an encrypted disk by Softlayer API through these methods.

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The encryption will be set automatically once it has completed the provision.

**Note** that encryption is only available in data centers with an asterisk (so called **Upgraded Data centers**).You may use the [SoftLayer_Network_Storage::getFileBlockEncryptedLocations](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_network_storage/getfileblockencryptedlocations) method to identify which they are.

Try the following REST requests:

For **Block** storage:

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder
method: POST

{
"parameters":[
    {
    "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_AsAService",
    "location": 449494,
    "packageId": 759,
    "volumeSize": 500,
    "prices": [
    {
        "id": 189433
    }, 
    {
        "id": 189443
    }, 
    {
        "id": 193373
    }, 
    {
        "id": 194633
    }, 
    {
        "id": 193433
    }],

    "osFormatType": {
        "keyName": "LINUX"
    }
}
]
}
```

For **File** Storage:

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder
method: POST

{
"parameters":[
    {
    "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_AsAService",
    "location": 449600,
    "packageId": 759,
    "volumeSize": 250,
    "prices": [
    {
        "id": 189433
    }, 
    {
        "id": 189453
    }, 
    {
        "id": 192043
    }, 
    {
        "id": 193013
    }, 
    {
        "id": 192053
    }
    ],
    "osFormatType": {
        "keyName": "LINUX"
    }
    }
    ]
}
```

For more information please see below:

https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/migrate-file-storage-encrypted-file-storage

https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/faqs/1483#7277

Comment: I´m updating the answer, adding request to Order File&Block storage

Comment: Updated answer, please see above.

Comment: Thank you. And Could I run some command to check encryption status?

Comment: Yes, you may use the following request as example, hasEncryptionAtRest property should be "true" for encrypted volumes.

https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/12345678/getObject?objectMask=mask[accountId, username,capacityGb,id,notes,hasEncryptionAtRest]

Comment: No problem Edward.

Comment: Ok, cool. It returned 'true'. But I checked the disk created from package 222 was also 'hasEncryptionAtRest': true.